# How to Count Repeating Work For Each Department

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I am currently trying to work out how I can count work that has been to a department before being sent out to another.

For example if I have a job that started at Dept A and was then sent to Dept B and nothing else than that count should be 0, but if it went back from Dept B to Dept A again then I need it to count 1.

This would be the same if it then went from Dept A to B as in this case we would have 2 Departments that have the piece work back and forth.

The logics are not based on where the job initially started from, it is more about counting the values where the job has gone back to a Department that it had previously been to in the chain AS long as it has been to a different department in between. For example based on time values, I could have a situation where the job has been worked on in Dept A, a couple of times sequentially therefore the count will stay 0. This will only be counted if it went elsewhere and then came back to the original department.

If somebody could please advise on how I could write this query, as at present I am able to write a count for each Department but its the bit, if the work has been in the department before.

The following are my create and insert statements. Also just to clarify this is being written in version 11 of Oracle.

create table

```
CREATE TABLE "TEST_COUNT"   
   ( "P_DATE" DATE,   
 "MAIN_DEPT" VARCHAR2(6 BYTE)  
  )
```

insert

```
Insert into TEST_COUNT (P_DATE,MAIN_DEPT) values (to_date('17-FEB-16 12:03:36','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),'Dept A');  
Insert into TEST_COUNT (P_DATE,MAIN_DEPT) values (to_date('17-FEB-16 12:16:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),'Dept B');  
Insert into TEST_COUNT (P_DATE,MAIN_DEPT) values (to_date('17-FEB-16 12:16:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),'Dept A');  
Insert into TEST_COUNT (P_DATE,MAIN_DEPT) values (to_date('17-FEB-16 12:16:03','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),'Dept B');  
Insert into TEST_COUNT (P_DATE,MAIN_DEPT) values (to_date('17-FEB-16 12:20:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),'Dept B');  
Insert into TEST_COUNT (P_DATE,MAIN_DEPT) values (to_date('17-FEB-16 12:21:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),'Dept B');  
Insert into TEST_COUNT (P_DATE,MAIN_DEPT) values (to_date('17-FEB-16 12:33:49','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),'Dept A');  
Insert into TEST_COUNT (P_DATE,MAIN_DEPT) values (to_date('17-FEB-16 12:49:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),'Dept A');  
Insert into TEST_COUNT (P_DATE,MAIN_DEPT) values (to_date('04-APR-16 21:44:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),'Dept A');  
Insert into TEST_COUNT (P_DATE,MAIN_DEPT) values (to_date('04-APR-16 21:44:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),'Dept B');  
Insert into TEST_COUNT (P_DATE,MAIN_DEPT) values (to_date('04-APR-16 21:44:54','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),'Dept B');  
Insert into TEST_COUNT (P_DATE,MAIN_DEPT) values (to_date('04-APR-16 21:50:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),'Dept B');  
Insert into TEST_COUNT (P_DATE,MAIN_DEPT) values (to_date('04-APR-16 21:50:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),'Dept B');
```

Comment: You'll need a unique identifier for the job. Otherwise you'll never know which of the records is the same job being passed from department to department. You need to add an extra column (say, JOB_ID) where every job is given an identification number, then when a job is passed from one department to another it keeps the same ID.

Comment: Thanks Ambulare for your response. Currently all i have is the main job id but this isnt unique, this is just a customer number thats repeated for all of the above so not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

I assume there are typos in your input data - the timestamps are probably all distinct (duplicates really make no sense in this problem). Also, if you have a `job_id` column somewhere, the solution works with almost no change - you need to add `job_id` to the `SELECT`, `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses, and add `partition by job_id` to the analytic clause of `lag()`.

The solution works by adding a flag of 0 (or ANYTHING that is not `null`, really!) to a row whenever the `MAIN_DEPT` changes (including the very first row), and `null` otherwise. Then the outer query groups by `MAIN_DEPT` (and `job_id` if it exists), counts the flag (meaning only non-null values), it selects only the groups with a count of 2 or more, and subtracts 1 from the counts because that's your requirement. This is a direct application of the **start-of-group** technique (the name of the technique I use in this solution).

```
select MAIN_DEPT, count(flag) - 1 as ct
from   ( select P_DATE, MAIN_DEPT, 
                case when MAIN_DEPT = lag(MAIN_DEPT) over (order by P_DATE)
                     then null else 0 end   as flag
         from   TEST_COUNT
       )
where flag is not null   --  optional, but it may speed up the query (to be tested!)
group by MAIN_DEPT
having count(flag) > 1
order by MAIN_DEPT   --   ORDER BY is optional
;


MAIN_DEPT      CT
--------- -------
Dept A          2
Dept B          2
```

Comment: Thanks mathguy. The issue I have with my dataset is there is no sequence number to identify which event presides over another hence the duplicate timestamps.What I have within my dataset is the customer number which is unique hence I didnt include in my sample dataset as I didnt think it would make any difference. In regards to the above, do i need to add a flag column? Thanks btw...

Comment: No, you don't need to add a `flag` column. That is added by the subquery in the solution, and used completely by the outer query. You don't need it in the inputs or in the output! My observation about duplicate timestamps is this: what happened to the job at a duplicate timestamp, was it SIMULTANEOUSLY given by dept A to dept B and also by dept B to dept A? What else does a duplicate timestamp mean?

Comment: mathguy, thanks for your response. Whats happened is that my colleague has created a new table and picked out the columns he required, one of the main ones had a sequence number that gave the order of the jobs and he didnt bring this through. Unfortunately he is on leave and I dont have access to the main table hence I was trying to fix this with what I had. From the table, the job has been passed on from Dept A to B but because of the timestamps it is difficult to understand the order.